# HotSwap with Hybris - Not working for Hybris Storefront Extension codes

Tags: tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud, jrebel, hotswap, dcevm

I have installed altjvm in my local machine and used hotswap from https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent/releases for Hot Deployment in Hybris. The hybris server is starting properly, but for the first time, the ***ant clean all*** is taking about ***30 minutes*** and ***the server start up*** is taking about ***40 minutes***. For any change in facades or populators, the change is getting reflected by building only the required extension.

But the issue is with the storefront extension. Whenever any change is made in the storefront extension, I’m getting “***Unable create CtClass for URI ‘<>_tag.class'*** ” error for all the tag files and the pages are not opening after that.

**Hybris Version used:** 6.7

**DCEVM version:** DCEVM-8u181-installer-build2.jar

**java version:** “1.8.0_191”

**OS:** Windows 10 pro.

If anyone know something about this issue, please let me know.

Comment: You have the same issue here: https://blogs.sap.com/2018/11/01/hotswap-with-hybris-a-free-open-source-alternative-to-jrebel/#comment-497355

Unfortunately, it doesn't share any solution.

Comment: @geffchang  the issue was posted by me only in blogs.sap.com. Please let me know if you have any resolution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue here.

Eventually, the process finishes and I can see my changes in storefront (i'm 90% sure of this info), but it takes a long time.

Looks like it's building the entire application

edit: well, I'll have to spend some time and try to make it work, hopefully I'll be back with an solution and we will not have to spend a river of money on jrebel :b